# Re-entering US from Mexico

Tags: visas, usa, esta, mexico

I am currently in the US on a J1 visa which will expire in 30 days. I am then travelling to Mexico. Would I be allowed to re-enter the US after 2 weeks from Mexico on an ESTA for one week?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you returning for the reason your J1 was issued? In other words are going to keep doing the work/study/etc. when you return to the US, or is that finished?

Comment: No, I am returning for a one week vacation

Comment: You've been in the US for some time on a J1, then you go to Mexico, and then you want to go back to the US for vacation for a week? Why not do the US vacation before you go to the US?

Comment: I am planning on staying with a friend when I re enter the US and that is the only available time for her and it’s once my J1 expires. That’s why I am wondering if I can re enter on an ESTA